# Как можно увеличить скорость работы при конвертировании изображения?

Tags: python, pyqt5, изображения, qimage

Есть приложение на pyqt5, которое может преобразовывать изображение в оттенки серого и т.д, но делает оно это очень медленно.

Интересно, можно ли как-то ускорить его?

```
import math
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QDesktopWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QFileDialog, QPushButton, QSlider


class Colors(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.img = ''
        self.label = QLabel(self.window())
        self.label.resize(670, 500)
        self.label.move(25, 25)
        self.pixmap = QPixmap()

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.resize(1200, 900)
        self.center()
        self.setWindowTitle('Center')

        self.h_label = QLabel('H', self)
        self.h_label.move(30, 716)
        self.h_sld = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.h_sld.setRange(0, 360)
        self.h_sld.setPageStep(1)
        self.h_sld.move(50, 700)
        self.h_sld.resize(500, 50)

        self.s_label = QLabel('S', self)
        self.s_label.move(30, 736)
        self.s_sld = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.s_sld.setRange(0, 100)
        self.s_sld.setPageStep(1)
        self.s_sld.move(50, 720)
        self.s_sld.resize(500, 50)

        self.v_label = QLabel('V', self)
        self.v_label.move(30, 756)
        self.v_sld = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.v_sld.setRange(0, 100)
        self.v_sld.setPageStep(1)
        self.v_sld.move(50, 740)
        self.v_sld.resize(500, 50)

        choose_img = QPushButton('Открыть', self)
        choose_img.move(700, 50)
        choose_img.clicked.connect(self.open_on_click)

        save_img = QPushButton('Сохранить', self)
        save_img.move(800, 50)
        save_img.clicked.connect(self.save_on_click)

        to_grey = QPushButton('RGB -> Grey', self)
        to_grey.move(700, 85)
        to_grey.clicked.connect(self.to_grey_on_click)

        to_red = QPushButton('RGB -> Red', self)
        to_red.move(800, 85)
        to_red.clicked.connect(self.to_red_on_click)

        to_green = QPushButton('RGB -> Green', self)
        to_green.move(700, 120)
        to_green.clicked.connect(self.to_green_on_click)

        to_blue = QPushButton('RGB -> Blue', self)
        to_blue.move(800, 120)
        to_blue.clicked.connect(self.to_blue_on_click)

        to_hsv = QPushButton('To HSV', self)
        to_hsv.move(700, 730)
        to_hsv.clicked.connect(self.to_hsv)

    def to_grey_on_click(self):
        img = self.pixmap.toImage()
        for x in range(img.width()):
            for y in range(img.height()):
                r = QColor(img.pixel(x, y)).red()
                g = QColor(img.pixel(x, y)).green()
                b = QColor(img.pixel(x, y)).blue()
                a = (0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b)
                img.setPixel(x, y, QColor(a, a, a).rgb())
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap(img))
        self.show()

    def to_red_on_click(self):
        img = self.pixmap.toImage()
        for x in range(img.width()):
            for y in range(img.height()):
                r = QColor(img.pixel(x, y)).red()
                img.setPixel(x, y, QColor(r, 0, 0).rgb())
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap(img))
        self.show()

    def to_green_on_click(self):
        img = self.pixmap.toImage()
        for x in range(img.width()):
            for y in range(img.height()):
                g = QColor(img.pixel(x, y)).green()
                img.setPixel(x, y, QColor(0, g, 0).rgb())
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap(img))
        self.show()

    def to_blue_on_click(self):
        img = self.pixmap.toImage()
        for x in range(img.width()):
            for y in range(img.height()):
                b = QColor(img.pixel(x, y)).blue()
                img.setPixel(x, y, QColor(0, 0, b).rgb())
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap(img))
        self.show()

    def open_file_name_dialog(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        filename, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", "",
                                                  "Images (*.jpg *.jpeg *.png)", options=options)
        if filename:
            self.pixmap = QPixmap(filename).scaled(670, 500)

    def to_hsv(self):
        self.hsv()

    def hsv(self):
        img = self.pixmap.toImage()
        for x in range(img.width()):
            for y in range(img.height()):
                r = QColor(img.pixel(x, y)).red()
                g = QColor(img.pixel(x, y)).green()
                b = QColor(img.pixel(x, y)).blue()
                h, s, v = self.rgb2hsv(r, g, b)
                dh = self.h_sld.value()
                ds = self.s_sld.value() * 0.01
                dv = self.v_sld.value() * 0.01
                h1 = (h + dh) % 360
                s1 = max(min(s + ds, 1), 0)
                v1 = max(min(v + dv, 1), 0)
                r1, g1, b1 = self.hsv2rgb(h1, s1, v1)
                img.setPixel(x, y, QColor(r1, g1, b1).rgb())
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap(img))
        self.show()

    def rgb2hsv(self, r, g, b):
        r, g, b = r / 255.0, g / 255.0, b / 255.0
        mx = max(r, g, b)
        mn = min(r, g, b)
        df = mx - mn
        if mx == mn:
            h = 0
        elif mx == r:
            h = (60 * ((g - b) / df) + 360) % 360
        elif mx == g:
            h = (60 * ((b - r) / df) + 120) % 360
        elif mx == b:
            h = (60 * ((r - g) / df) + 240) % 360
        if mx == 0:
            s = 0
        else:
            s = df / mx
        v = mx
        return h, s, v

    def hsv2rgb(self, h, s, v):
        h = float(h)
        s = float(s)
        v = float(v)
        h60 = h / 60.0
        h60f = math.floor(h60)
        hi = int(h60f) % 6
        f = h60 - h60f
        p = v * (1 - s)
        q = v * (1 - f * s)
        t = v * (1 - (1 - f) * s)
        r, g, b = 0, 0, 0
        if hi == 0:
            r, g, b = v, t, p
        elif hi == 1:
            r, g, b = q, v, p
        elif hi == 2:
            r, g, b = p, v, t
        elif hi == 3:
            r, g, b = p, q, v
        elif hi == 4:
            r, g, b = t, p, v
        elif hi == 5:
            r, g, b = v, p, q
        r, g, b = int(r * 255), int(g * 255), int(b * 255)
        return r, g, b

    def open_on_click(self):
        self.open_file_name_dialog()
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

    def save_on_click(self):
        self.save_file_dialog()

    def save_file_dialog(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        filename, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "QFileDialog.getSaveFileName()", "",
                                                  "Images (*.jpg *.jpeg *.png)", options=options)
        if filename:
            self.label.pixmap().save(filename)

    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        import sys
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)

        ex = Colors()
        ex .show()

        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Да, цикл по пикселям на скрипте это очень медленно, если только это не JavaScript. Как ускорить - написать модуль на C, который будет обрабатывать изображения, или использовать PIL.

Comment: PIL и numpy здесь вас спасут.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первую очередь измерьте время выполнения методов с вложенными  циклами. Убедитесь, что именно  они являются узким местом в вашем коде (это вероятно, но следует проверить). Это заодно позволит узнать насколько лучше (если лучше) другие варианты решения.

Для примера, вот медленная реализация приложения, которое показывает картинку, указанную в командной строке и преобразовывает её в оттенки серого по нажатию мышки, используя вложенные циклы из кода в вопросе:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Usage: to-grey <image>"""
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication, QColor, QIcon, QPixmap, QSize, QToolButton

def on_click():
    img = w.icon().pixmap(qsize).toImage()
    # XXX slow, don't do it
    for x in range(img.width()):
        for y in range(img.height()):
            r = QColor(img.pixel(x, y)).red()
            g = QColor(img.pixel(x, y)).green()
            b = QColor(img.pixel(x, y)).blue()
            a = (0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b)
            img.setPixel(x, y, QColor(a, a, a).rgb())
    w.setIcon(QIcon(QPixmap(img)))

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
if len(app.arguments()) != 2:
    sys.exit(__doc__)
w = QToolButton()
w.setIcon(QIcon(app.arguments()[1]))
qsize = QSize(300, 300)
w.setIconSize(qsize)
w.clicked.connect(on_click)
# center
w.adjustSize()  # update w.rect() now
w.move(app.desktop().screen().rect().center() - w.rect().center())
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Пример:

```
$ python3 to-gray.py ~/Pictures/example.jpg
```

Чтобы узнать какие вызовы отнимают наибольшее время, можно запустить скрипт с profiler:

```
$ python -mprofile --sort cumtime to-gray.py ~/Pictures/example.jpg
```

Сюрпризов нет, на `on_click()` уходит заметное время. При желании, можно построчно производительность померить:

```
$ pip install pprofile
$ pprofile --exclude-syspath to-gray.py ~/Pictures/example.jpg
```

Чтобы улучшить производительность, можно заменить вложенные циклы на векторные операции над numpy массивом.

Можно создать numpy массив, используя буфер из QImage, тогда изменения в numpy массиве автоматически будут отражаться в QImage:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Usage: to-grey <image>"""
import sys
import numpy as np         # $ pip install numpy
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication, QIcon, QImage, QPixmap, QSize, QToolButton

def on_click():
    # r = arr[..., 0]
    # g = arr[..., 1]
    # b = arr[..., 2]
    # a = (0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b)
    a = arr @ [0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722]  # np.dot
    # arr[..., 0] = a
    # arr[..., 1] = a
    # arr[..., 2] = a
    arr[...] = a[..., np.newaxis]

    w.setIcon(QIcon(QPixmap(qimage)))

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
if len(app.arguments()) != 2:
    sys.exit(__doc__)
w = QToolButton()
qimage = QImage(app.arguments()[1]).convertToFormat(QImage.Format_RGB888)
w.setIcon(QIcon(QPixmap(qimage)))
width, height = qimage.width(), qimage.height()
w.setIconSize(QSize(width, height))
ptr = qimage.bits()
ptr.setsize(qimage.byteCount())
arr = np.ndarray((height, width, 3),
                 dtype=np.uint8, buffer=ptr)  # share data
w.clicked.connect(on_click)
# center
w.adjustSize()  # update w.rect() now
w.move(app.desktop().screen().rect().center() - w.rect().center())
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

QPixmap свой внутренний буфер использует, поэтому после изменения массива, заново QPixmap создаётся в `on_click()`. Это требует на порядок меньше времени чем к примеру `np.dot` операция в `on_click()`.

Удобно проверять корректность конвертирования изображений и их производительность отдельно от GUI кода:

```
def rgb2gray_rgb(arr):
    a = arr @ [0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722]
    arr[...] = a[..., np.newaxis]
```

Посмотрите не предлагают ли такую функцию уже существующие пакеты, такие как scikit-image.

Для циклов, которые сложно в векторные операции превратить, можно cython использовать, [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/583548/23044).