# PyQt и skimage вывод изображение на форму

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, изображения

Как вывести изображение обработанное в skimage на форму.

```
img = io.imread(self.img1_dir)  
# Пробовал как из файла   
pixmap = QPixmap(img).scaled(300, 400)  
self.img1.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

Как вывести `img` на форму?

`img1`- QLable. Или нужно использовать другой виджет для вывода?

Comment: QLabel подходит. А в чем проблема у вас? io.imread что возвращает? Байты? Объект-похожий-на-файл?

Comment: @ gil9red байты возвращает

Comment: А гугление сказало, что возвращается массив numpy :)

Comment: А вы мой ответ проверяли? У меня нет skimage, поэтому проверить не было возможности. Но, код по идеи, правильный

Comment: @gil9red Спасибо. Он отлично работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
from io import BytesIO
from skimage.io import imread, imsave


img = imread(self.img1_dir)

# ...
# Что-то делаем с картинкой
# ...

bytes_io = BytesIO()

# Сохранение картинки в буфер
imsave(bytes_io, img)

# Достаем из буфера байты
img_data = bytes_io.getvalue()

pixmap = QPixmap()
pixmap.loadFromData(img_data)

pixmap = pixmap.scaled(300, 400)  

self.img1.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

---

Чтобы загрузить в `QPixmap` массив байт нужно вызвать у него метод [loadFromData](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#loadFromData-1)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы не сериализировать в байты, не копировать, не конвертировать лишний раз картинку, можно использовать общую память для numpy массива и QImage:

```
qimage = QImage(self.image_path).convertToFormat(QImage.Format_RGB888)
ptr = qimage.bits()
ptr.setsize(qimage.byteCount())
arr = np.ndarray((qimage.height(), qimage.width(), 3),
                 dtype=np.uint8, buffer=ptr)  # share data
```

После этого любые изменения в `arr` будут видны в `qimage`. К примеру, [чтобы цветную картинку серой сделать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/721018/23044):

```
# to gray
a = arr @ [0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722]  # np.dot
arr[...] = a[..., np.newaxis]
```

`QPixmap` следует новый создавать после каждого изменения:

```
self.image.setPixmap(QPixmap(qimage))
```

---

Если у вас уже есть numpy массив `arr` в нужном формате, тогда чтобы QImage создать:

```
height, width, _ = arr.shape
bytes_per_line = 3 * width
qimage = QImage(arr, width, height, bytes_per_line + 1, QImage.Format_RGB888)
```

См. [Convert Python Opencv Image (numpy array) to PyQt QPixmap image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34232632/4279)

Comment: Общая память -- это интересно :)

Comment: С QImage(последний пример) изображение разъезжается из-за `bytesPerLine + 1`

Comment: @Sonfire: в моих тестах именно с `bytes_per_line + 1` работает (если использовать `arr`, полученный выше). От источника `arr` может зависеть. Если для вас `bytes_per_line` работает, то хорошо.