# QLabel обработчик клика мышкой

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qlabel

Нужно чтобы при нажатии на Label происходило событие.
Нашел кое-какую информацию здесь [Clickable QLabel](https://wiki.qt.io/Clickable_QLabel/ru) и здесь [make QLabel clickable using PyQt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45575626/make-qlabel-clickable-using-pyqt5), но не пойму как использовать этот код.

Comment: иногда можно QToolButton вместо QLabel использовать, чтобы нажатие кнопки мыши обработать, [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/721290/23044)

Comment: у меня еще QLabel с рисунком - думаю QToolButton мне не подойдет. Клик по кнопке я и сам обработать могу

Comment: если вы нажмёте на ссылку, то увидите что именно случай "QLabel с рисунком" эмулируется¶ Ваш вопрос явно говорит что сами вы не можете обработать.

Comment: какую ссылку вы имеете ввиду? QToolButton это же кнопка

Comment: обычная QLabel не поддерживает нажатия мыши. В первом комментарии явно указано зачем QToolButton.

Comment: но можно сделать чтобы поддерживал. Мне нужно чтобы по рисунку можно было кликнуть - я решил использовать QLabel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/866573/201445) на вопрос про клики по `label`, увидел этот и решил добавить пример самой простой реализации кликабельного label'а:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QLabel, pyqtSignal, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QWidget

class ClickedLabel(QLabel):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(e)

        self.clicked.emit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    label_1 = ClickedLabel('Label 1')
    label_1.clicked.connect(lambda: print('label_1'))

    label_2 = ClickedLabel('Label 2')
    label_2.clicked.connect(lambda: print('label_2'))

    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(label_1)
    layout.addWidget(label_2)

    mw = QWidget()
    mw.setLayout(layout)
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Comment: Спасибо, но у меня этот код вызывает ошибку во время выполнения. Правда мой обработчик выглядит немного по-другому: label_1.clicked.connect(lambda state, x=id: self.method(x))

Comment: @MyNick, а что за ошибка?

Comment: я не знаю, скрипт запускаю с помощью IDLE и программа завершается с ошибкой. Как можно посмотреть ошибку?

Comment: наконец запустил ваш код. Работает. Спасибо. Может быть вы сможете ответить на другой мой вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/864825/orm-peewee-Удалить-запись-из-любой-таблицы

Comment: @MyNick, примите тогда мой ответ :) Посмотрел вопрос по ссылке, к сожалению, с peewee не работал, поэтому с ходу сказать как сделать не могу

Comment: Ладно. Выбрал ваш ответ лучшим

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте это:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *

class LabelClickable(QLabel):

    clicked = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LabelClickable, self).__init__(parent)

    # Этот обработчик событий для события `event`  может быть переопределен 
    # в подклассе для получения событий нажатия мыши для виджета.    
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.last = "Click"

    # Этот обработчик событий для события `event` может быть переопределен в подклассе, 
    # чтобы получать события переноса мыши для виджета.
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if self.last == "Click":
            QTimer.singleShot(QApplication.instance().doubleClickInterval(),
                              self.performSingleClickAction)
        else:
            self.clicked.emit(self.last)

    # Этот обработчик событий для события `event` может быть переопределен в подклассе 
    # для получения событий двойного щелчка мыши для виджета.
    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        self.last = "Double Click"

    def performSingleClickAction(self):
        if self.last == "Click":
            self.clicked.emit(self.last)


class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)    

        self.setWindowTitle("Label Clickable")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('E:\\_Qt\\img\\qt-logo.png'))
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
        self.setFixedSize(400, 511)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.labelImagen = LabelClickable(self)
        self.labelImagen.setGeometry(15, 15, 118, 130)
        self.labelImagen.setToolTip("Image")
        self.labelImagen.setCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)

        self.labelImagen.setStyleSheet("Qlabel {background-color: white; border: 1px solid "
                                       "#01DFD7; border-radius: 5px;}")
        # Здесь ваша картинка  --->  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv                                 
        self.pixmapImagen = QPixmap("E:\\_Qt\\img\\qt-logo.png").scaled(112, 128, Qt.KeepAspectRatio,
                                     Qt.SmoothTransformation)

        self.labelImagen.setPixmap(self.pixmapImagen)
        self.labelImagen.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.labelImagen.clicked.connect(self.Clic)

    def Clic(self, accion):
        QMessageBox.information(self, "Тип клика",
                                 "Вы сделали {}.                 ".format(accion))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex  = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо большое. Пробую...