# ORM Peewee. Удалить запись из любой таблицы

Tags: python, peewee

У меня есть метод для удаления записи из конкретной таблицы:

```
def del_record(self, id):
    Table1[id].delete_instance()
```

Можно ли в данном случае сделать так, чтобы можно было удалять запись из любой таблицы передавая например ее имя в качестве параметра?

Answer (score 1):

Тогда, может вручную составлять `SQL`-запрос на [удаление записи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_(SQL)) из таблицы?

```sql
DELETE FROM <Имя Таблицы> WHERE <Условие отбора записей>
```

Получится такой код:

```
def del_record(self, table_name, id):
    sql = "DELETE FROM {} WHERE id=?".format(table_name)
    db.execute_sql(query, (id,))
```

---

**PS.**

- Идею взял [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35445322/5909792).
- Подробнее про метод [db.execute_sql(query, values)](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Database.execute_sql): http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html?highlight=execute_sql
- Можно было подставить и `id` в запрос:

  ```
    sql = "DELETE FROM {} WHERE id={}".format(table_name, id)`
  ```

  Но зная про [sql-инъекции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0) и не зная откуда у вас придет `id`, решил сделать пример более правильно.

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_item(self, id, modelname):
    modelname[id].delete_instance()
```

В **modelname** передавайте название класса модели, в вашем случае это **Table1**.

Comment: нет, так работать не будет