# Как можно отслеживать нажатия на QLabel?

Tags: python, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qlabel, eventfilter

Мне понадобилось отслеживать нажатия на `QLabel` и выполнять функцию по нажатию. 
Как я понял, в 5-той версии *PyQt* стало невозможно на `QLabel` повесить сигнал `clicked()`.

Я пытался отслеживать нажатия с помощью `eventFilter`, но тут что-то не задалось. Т.к. нормальных доков нет, я не разобрался, как с этим работать.

Comment: Да и в 4-й версии нельзя было так делать. Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос вашу попытку с eventFilter

Comment: @gil9red только написал вопрос, сразу же разобрался с eventFilter... А разве в 4-й версии нельзя было вешать любые сигналы с помощью QtCore.QObject.connect?

Comment: Не, любые нельзя. Если у объекта есть сигнал, значит тот у него прописан и вызывается при каких-то событиях. Если вы делаете кликабельный label, то создаете сигнал `clicked`, переопределяете событие `mouseReleaseEvent` и в нем активируете сигнал: `self.clicked.emit()`. Те, то подконектился к этому сигналу, получит его при его активации. Раз сами решили вопрос, добавьте пожалуйста ответ с этим :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой пример кликабельного `label`'а, сделанного через наследование:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QLabel, pyqtSignal, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QWidget


class ClickedLabel(QLabel):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(e)

        self.clicked.emit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    label_1 = ClickedLabel('Label 1')
    label_1.clicked.connect(lambda: print('label_1'))

    label_2 = ClickedLabel('Label 2')
    label_2.clicked.connect(lambda: print('label_2'))

    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(label_1)
    layout.addWidget(label_2)

    mw = QWidget()
    mw.setLayout(layout)
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена. Оказалось, что eventFilter должен возвращать bool. Все решилось простым добавлением в конце return True.

Пример:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.Start()
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            #здесь выполняем код
        return True
    def Start(self):
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label.installEventFilter(self)
if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWin()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Мне кажется, я уже становлюсь доставучим :) Добавьте, пожалуйста, код :) Тема с eventFilter, по моему, очень запутанная, а добавление примера кода поможет многим

Comment: @gil9red да нет, я понимаю. Сам целыми днями лазаю по просторам интернета, чтобы хоть что-то найти про какую-либо функцию, т.к. создатели pyqt не позаботились об адекватной документации.

Comment: Я всегда смотрю в документацию Qt. Например по eventFilter есть пример: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter

Comment: @gil9red мне сложно переделывать примеры с C++ на Python

Comment: Думаю, мне немного проще -- у меня с++ первый язык :) но считаю, что там несложно -- названия виджетов, методов одинаковое, сложности могут быть в синтаксисе, но и там нет проблем, если немного поразбираться :)

Answer (score 1):

Кликабельный Label с использованием `eventFilter` (как вариант):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class EventFilter(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(EventFilter, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Фильтр событий eventFilter")
        self.resize(400, 300)

        self.label1 = QLabel("Кликабельнай \nLabel\nПожалуйста, \nнажмите")
        self.label2 = QLabel("Label2")
        self.label3 = QLabel("Label3")
        self.labelState = QLabel("Результат кликов")

        self.image1 = QImage("E:/_Qt/img/qt-logo.png")

        self.label1.installEventFilter(self)

        mainLayout = QGridLayout(self)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.label1, 5, 0)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.label2, 5, 1)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.label3, 5, 2)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.labelState, 6, 1)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        # Только фильтровать событие label1, переписать его поведение, 
        # другие события будут проигнорированы
        if obj == self.label1:   
            # здесь отфильтруйте событие mouse и перепишите его поведение
            if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress: 
                mouseEvent = QMouseEvent(event)
                if mouseEvent.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
                    self.labelState.setText("Нажали левую кнопку мыши")
                elif mouseEvent.buttons() == Qt.MidButton:
                    self.labelState.setText("Нажали среднюю кнопку мыши")
                elif mouseEvent.buttons() == Qt.RightButton:
                    self.labelState.setText("Нажали правую кнопку мыши")

                ''' Преобразование размера изображения '''
                transform = QTransform()
                transform.scale(0.5, 0.5)
                tmp = self.image1.transformed(transform)
                self.label1.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(tmp))

            # здесь отфильтруйте событие выпуска мыши и перепишите его поведение
            if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:  
                self.labelState.setText("Отпустили кнопку мыши")
                self.label1.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(self.image1))

        return QDialog.eventFilter(self, obj, event) 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app    = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = EventFilter()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]