# переменная при импорте модуля

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qss

Имею:
*Windows 10, Python 3.7, PyQt5, 

sip, pip, Pyinstaller, pywin32, pypiwin32, sqlalchemy, pyqt5-tools*

нужно это (работает):

```
THEME = "Light"
if THEME == "Light": from Styles import Light
elif THEME == "Dark": from Styles import Dark
```

преобразовать примерно в это (не работает):

```
THEME = "Light"
from Styles import THEME
```

Похожий пример:

либо в каждой кнопке писать:

```
THEME = "Light"
if THEME=="Light": from Styles import Light
elif THEME=="Dark": from Styles import Dark

....
    self.pb1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
    self.pb1.setObjectName("pb1")
    self.pb1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 10, 10))
    if THEME=="Light": self.pb1.setStyleSheet(Light.Button2("pb1"))
    elif THEME=="Dark": self.pb1.setStyleSheet(Dark.Button2("pb1"))
    icon = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.On)
    self.pb1.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(10, 10))
    self.pb1.setIcon(icon)

    self.pb2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
    self.pb2.setObjectName("pb2")
    self.pb2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 10, 10))
    if THEME=="Light": self.pb2.setStyleSheet(Light.Button2("pb2"))
    elif THEME=="Dark": self.pb2.setStyleSheet(Dark.Button2("pb2"))
    icon = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.On)
    self.pb2.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(10, 10))
    self.pb2.setIcon(icon)
....
    self.pb_n = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
    self.pb_n.setObjectName("pb_n")
    self.pb_n.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 10, 10))
    if THEME=="Light": self.pb_n.setStyleSheet(Light.Button2("pb_n"))
    elif THEME=="Dark": self.pb_n.setStyleSheet(Dark.Button2("pb_n"))
    icon = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.On)
    self.pb_n.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(10, 10))
    self.pb_n.setIcon(icon)
(n-20-100 кнопок)
```

А если захотелось третью или четвертую тему добавить нужно весь код перелопатить...

либо сделать приблизительно так (но почему-то не работает):

```
THEME = "Light"
from Styles import THEME

....
    self.pb1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
    self.pb1.setObjectName("pb1")
    self.pb1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 10, 10))
    self.pb1.setStyleSheet(THEME.Button2("pb1"))
    icon = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.On)
    self.pb1.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(10, 10))
    self.pb1.setIcon(icon)

    self.pb2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
    self.pb2.setObjectName("pb2")
    self.pb2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 10, 10))
    self.pb2.setStyleSheet(THEME.Button2("pb2"))
    icon = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.On)
    self.pb2.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(10, 10))
    self.pb2.setIcon(icon)
....
    self.pb_n = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
    self.pb_n.setObjectName("pb_n")
    self.pb_n.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 10, 10))
    self.pb_n.setStyleSheet(THEME.Button2("pb_n"))
    icon = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.On)
    self.pb_n.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(10, 10))
    self.pb_n.setIcon(icon)
(n-20-100 кнопок)
```

Это называется оптимизация кода.

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста, что вас не устраивает в первом варианте и опубликуйте модуль `Styles.py`

Comment: к примеру: self.Label.setStyleSheet(Light.Button2("Label")) хочу запихнуть переменную в import но не знаю как, если оставить так, то придется во многих частях кода делать проверку if, если будет возможность запихнуть переменную, то тогда эту проверку можно сделать лишь раз вначале кода. Это как бы очевидно.

Comment: Вы что-то делаете не так. Опубликуйте минимальный пример и напишите, что вы хотите сделать и вам помогут.

Comment: Если поточнее посмотреть то Styles это директория, в которой находятся два файла Light.py и Dark.py, я хочу чтобы import читал содержимое переменной THEME, вместо этого он читает название переменной как текст. почему так? в коде основной программы 3-4 десятка кнопок которым нужен SetStyleSheet (а он записан в Light.py или Dark.py), соответственно и тут нужен такой же принцип.

Comment: я так понял, что вы экспериментируете со  `Style Sheet` ? Посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/868101/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-border-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-icon-%d0%bd%d0%b0-qpushbutton/868178#868178

Comment: Да блин, я хочу чтобы основная программа читала темы из разных файлов! Темы (как раз те самые SetStyleSheet в виде кодов цвета #xxxxxx ). Проще говоря мне придется для каждой строки SetStyleSheet вводить If и дубликат как в примере выше....

Comment: Опубликуйте свой приме и напишите, что вы хотите сделать и я постараюсь вам помочь !!!

Comment: Добавил пояснение... надеюсь поможет.

Comment: Так работает `th = from Styles __import__(THEME)` ? Использовать th как имя модуля.

Comment: Нет не срабатывает. Даже если сделать строку суммированием "from Styles import" + THEME то надо как то применить этот текст как команду. а th = from Styles __import__(THEME) просто присваивает значение переменной th

Comment: ошибка SyntaxError: invalid syntax на from

Comment: если убрать "th =" так же ругается на __import__

Answer (score 0):

Ваша беда в том, что вы не публикуете свой пример.

Я увидел вашу задачу так. Попробуйте нажимать на кнопки.

```
import sys
from functools import partial
from PyQt5     import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

QSS = """
QPushButton::checked{
    background-color: blue;      
}
"""

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, r, c, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.r = r
        self.c = c
        self._list = [ [0 for _ in range(c)] for _ in range(r) ] 
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)

        for i in range(r):
            for j in range(c):
                button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('  {}-{}'.format(i, j))
                button.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("LightOff.png"))   
                button.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(34, 34))
#                button.setFlat(True)                    # попробуйте раскомментировать
                button.setCheckable(True)
                layout.addWidget(button, i, j)
                button.clicked.connect(partial(self.clickButton, i, j))
                button.setStyleSheet(QSS)
                self._list[i][j] = button

        self.pbLight = QtWidgets.QPushButton("ButtonLight")
        self.pbLight.clicked.connect(self.clickLight)
        self.pbDark  = QtWidgets.QPushButton("ButtonDark")
        self.pbDark.clicked.connect(self.clickDark)
        layout.addWidget(self.pbLight, i+1, 0, 1, c//2)
        layout.addWidget(self.pbDark,  i+1, c//2, 1, c//2)

    def clickButton(self, i, j, state):
        if state: self._list[i][j].setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("LightOn.png"))
        else:     self._list[i][j].setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("LightOff.png"))

    def clickLight(self):
        for i in range(self.r):
            for j in range(self.c):        
                if self._list[i][j].isChecked() : self._list[i][j].click()

    def clickDark(self):
        for i in range(self.r):
            for j in range(self.c):        
                if not self._list[i][j].isChecked() : self._list[i][j].click()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("fusion")
    row = 5                 # количество строк
    column = 10             # количество столбцов
    w = Widget(row, column)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: задача состоит в том чтобы скормить переменную в названии модуля или команды. переменная THEME с выбираемым мной значением Light или Dark или еще какое... запихнуть вместо import  Light или SetStyleSheet(Light....)

Comment: в bat коде это выглядело бы так: THEME="любое значение" import %THEME% или SetStyleSheet(%THEME%) и это сработало бы, так как bat читает значения переменных.

Comment: я уже не знаю как более доходчиво объяснить постановку задачи...